# Dynamics CRM 4.0 related entity limitation

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have created an custom related entity for Quote in CRM 4.0. when i revise a quote, i want to  make read only all of records belong of that related entity.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add Javascript code on the form of the related entity.
In the related entity form, check if the lookup field has data then loop through each field and disable it, if not then do nothing.

Here is the code for disabling all fields"

```
for (var index in crmForm.all) {
   var control = crmForm.all[index];
   if (control.req && (control.Disabled != null)) {
      control.Disabled = true;
   }
}
```